# Boost serilization code crashes

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

My program is crashing on the `boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs)` function. My boost version is 1.58 and OS is Ubuntu 16.04

```
void saveToFile()
{
    string fileName ("/tmp/test.txt") ;

    ofstream ofs(fileName.c_str());
    if (ofs.good())
    {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
            ar & fileName;
            return;
    }
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
      saveToFile();
      return 0;
 }
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
    #0  0x00007f85e9252418 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
    #1  0x00007f85e925401a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
    #2  0x00007f85e929472a in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7f85e93ad6b0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
        at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
    #3  0x00007f85e929cf4a in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=<optimized out>, ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7f85e93aa48f "free(): invalid pointer", action=3)
        at malloc.c:5007
    #4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3868
    #5  0x00007f85e92a0abc in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2969
    #6  0x00000000004082fe in saveToFile () at main.cpp:56
    #7  0x00000000004083b0 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7ffc120a4fa8) at main.cpp:68
```

Comment: Hmm, but the stack trace doesn't point into that constructor. Can you step through it and find more about where exactly this happens? Is this the exact code where the crash happens? The stack trace mentions lines like 68, which is a lot more than the snippet you pasted.

Comment: I'd suggest checking compilation flags on your executable vs. boost_system/boost_serialization. Do a full rebuild.